# Purpose for catching all the monsters?

Tags: dragon-quest-v

At a certain point in the game you are able to "befriend" or catch monsters to be in your party. Is there a purpose for befriending all the recruit able monsters, like a special item or different ending?

Comment: To be the very best. Like no one ever was.

Comment: To catch them is my real test. To train them is my cause.

Comment: Like you need a reason.

Answer (score 1):

The only objective to catch'em is to have them. Pokemon style.

> Dragon Quest V: Bride of Heaven features a system whereby some
>   monsters that you fight can be recruited to join your party.  The
>   recruitment system is fairly simple but there are a lot of nuances
>   that can make the process seem frustrating if you don't understand how
>   it works.
>
> 3) HOW MANY MONSTERS CAN I TAKE WITH ME WHILE ADVENTURING?
>
> You can have up 8 characters with you at any time, but this includes
>   the main  characters and any other human companions you have with you.
>   Any Extra  monsters who do not fit in the wagon must stay with Mr.
>   Monster or be released back into the wild.
>
> 4) WHAT IS THE MAXIMUM NUMBER OF MONSTERS I CAN RECRUIT?
>
> In principal there is no limit to the number of monsters that you can
>   recruit. Mr. Monster will accommodate as many monsters as you can
>   bring him.  If you get right down to it, there are 65 regular monsters
>   that are recruitable, and you can obtain a maximum of 3 of the same
>   monster.  In addition to this, there are 4 special recruits that you
>   can have at any one time in the game.  If you do the math, that works
>   out to 199 monsters that you can recruit.  If you manage to get them
>   all, I tip my hat to you.
>
> 5) HOW MANY MONSTERS CAN I LEAVE WITH MR. MONSTER?
>
> If you can catch 'em, he can hold 'em.  Given the answer to the above
>   question, he can accommodate up to 199 monsters.  His cave must be
>   bigger than it looks!

[**Source**](http://www.gamefaqs.com/snes/588292-dragon-quest-v/faqs/59545)

Comment: I do appreciate the post but your example of pokemon is kind of off, since when you collect all the pokemon you then get rewarded with more pokemon (Black and White) to collect. Since DQV has a monster journal of sorts it leads me to believe that there is a purpose for collecting them all. But thank you again.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't resist =)

Comment: @stay as you can see there is no rewards on catch all 62 monsters. they are only good to help you in the fight

Comment: The only reason why I haven't given your answer the green-light is because it really doesn't have anything regarding the Big Book of Beasts and the rewards that open up for collecting monsters. Having done some googling I have found that certain things get unlocked for amount of mobs/kills/recruits you achieve. But I cannot find what exactly you receive, so unfortunately this question will remain open till someone can give a listing of those rewards. Thank you though for the effort sir. :]